# How to run init.sql using docker-compose.yml?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, init

I'm creating a SQL server in docker container using docker-compose.yml, but i can't execute my init.sql when i run docker

- Code from docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    mssql-service:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest # Or whatever version you want
        container_name: mssql
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        environment:
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - SA_PASSWORD=my_password
            - MSSQL_PID=Developer
            - MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=True
        volumes:
            - sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql
            - C:/Users/joel_/Documents/GitLab/Emaresa/apps/api/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

- code from init.sql

```sql
USE master;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'my_database')
CREATE DATABASE my_database;
GO
```

my folder:

```
project/
│   .gitignore
│   alembic.ini
│   database.env
│   docker-command.bash
│   docker-compose.yml
│   init.sql
│   poetry.lock
│   pyproject.toml
```

hope someone help me with this because i didn't figure it out how to execute init.sql and create my_database

Comment: _/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/_ is the path considered by MySQL and Postgres containers, from what I read in the documentation, it doesn't work like that for the mssql one: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-customize#modify-the-setupsql-file

Comment: yeah, I read it. is there a way to create a database when sql server has started using docker?

Comment: Both the entrypoint in the MySQL and Postgress servers and the one for mssql does not act like that, they will only execute the sql files if there was not initialisation of the DB. This is up to you to write your own entrypoint to fit your need, though.

Comment: my command from docker-compe don't execute init.sql, i don't know what else to do

Comment: Have you looked at [twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app) by way of [Configure and customize SQL Server Docker containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-configure) yet? The specific example is for running a NodeJS app with a SQL Server container in Docker, but the techniques for setting up SQL Server inside a Docker container apply no matter which applications you're trying to build around it.